# Memory profiling of a running python application

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, ponyorm

I have a `flask` application that uses `pony` as its ORM. The application incrementally increases its memory usage with every request to the service. I need to measure the memory usage of different parts of the program to find the problem.
Unfortunately, as the program does not return its execution and is always running I could not use memory profiling tools such as [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). How can I profile memory usage of a continuously running application?

Comment: memory_profiler can write to stream or standard log file.

Comment: Please take a look at `perf-mem`, `perf-kmem` and `pref-record`. You can continuously record stats with `perf-record` and then analyse using `perf-stat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scalene](https://github.com/emeryberger/scalene) is able to generate profiling output every `N` seconds.

Comment: But, how to run Scalene with a Flask app?